# momentjs locale for 'Today' and 'Yesterday'

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
    const showDateDivider =
        !previousDate || !moment(date).isSame(previousDate, 'day')
    if (showDateDivider) {
        if (moment().isSame(date, 'day')) {
            return 'TODAY'
        } else if (moment().isSame(moment(date).add(1, 'day'), 'day')) {
            return 'YESTERDAY'
        } else if (moment().isSame(date, 'week')) {
            return moment(date).format('dddd')
        } else {
            return moment(date).format('ll')
        }
    } else {
        return null
    }
```

this is code for date divider(or whatever it is called, usually we use it in chatbox)

this work fine, I am able to return locale date time thanks to momentjs

however, do note that I hardcoded "TODAY" and "YESTERDAY", how can I get the locale of "TODAY" and "YESTERDAY" from moment(or is it even exists)?

Comment: use `locale()` method chained in moment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, you can use `moment().calendar()` : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/

and a little trick to remove the time (there is no other solution proposed by moment js.)

```js
moment.locale('fr');
const showDateDivider = function(date) {
        if (moment().isSame(date, 'day')) {
            return  moment().calendar().split(" ")[0]
        } else if (moment().isSame(moment(date).add(1, 'day'), 'day')) {
            return moment(date).calendar().split(" ")[0]
        } else if (moment().isSame(date, 'week')) {
            return moment(date).format('dddd')
        } else {
            return moment(date).format('ll')
   }
}
   
document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML = 
showDateDivider(new Date()) + '</br>'
document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML += showDateDivider(moment(new Date()).add(-1, 'day').toDate()) + '</br></br>'


moment.locale('es');

document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML += 
showDateDivider(new Date()) + '</br>'
document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML += showDateDivider(moment(new Date()).add(-1, 'day').toDate()) + '</br>'



document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML += showDateDivider(moment(new Date()).add(-2, 'day').toDate()) + '</br>'
document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML += showDateDivider(moment(new Date()).add(-1, 'week').toDate())
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<h3></h3>
```